# How to get invoice key

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, invoice

I'd like to use the Magento's print feature in my module to have the invoice pdf of a programmatically created order. For that I'd like to get the url that Magento back end uses to print the invoice.
eg : `http://localhost/magento1/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/104/key/eaf550ef39cc92e93b562994019fde14/`
[image]

My question is how can I get that key to build the url that retrieves the invoice pdf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write below code

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/104/");
```

and it will autometically add key

Comment: This generate the following link : `http://localhost/magento1/index.php/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/key/1c762f48f0b4a305a038d599b84bda83/`.  This does not add the invoice_id (104 in our example). I don't know why it does not add the invoice_id ...

Comment: Is it a bug in Magento ... ?

Comment: @androniennn check updated answer

Comment: I already tested it (adding a `/` after 104), but it negligents it .

Comment: @androniennn check updated answer

Comment: It generates now this link `http://localhost/magento1/index.php//sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/104/key/7a404e7599e10f550d17179ac4281dd7/`. No `admin` ..

Comment: @androniennn check final updated answer may be it solve all errors

Comment: Yes! Now it's working ! I have this `http://localhost/magento1/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/104/key/7a404e7599e10f550d17179ac4281dd7/`. Is it normal that I do not have the same key ?

Comment: @androniennn Magento always generate unique key everytime, so dont worry

Comment: Other question please, how did you know that there is a helper for that feature ? Is there any place to look to have all helpers ? (I don't want to open a whole new thread for that question {Accepted your answer} )

Comment: @androniennn, I have written same kind of code abt 1 year ago so that's why I know , and from my study I know that There is always this kind of function available for getting keys whether its `form_key` or `url_key`

Comment: After testing, I can confirm that we should have the same key as in the adminhtml invoice page. I have exactly the same URL(with the same `invoice_id`) but with different key `http://localhost/magento1/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/104/key/7a404e7599e10f550d17179ac4281dd7/` it redirects me to backend dashboard .. If I replace with the backend key, it works .

Comment: @androniennn I am not sure but you can try this `Mage::helper("sales")->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/104/");`

Comment: I have this : `Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Helper_Data::getUrl()`.